# Adding OkHttpClient interceptor makes the request proceed multiple times

Tags: android, httpclient, interceptor

I was trying to add refresh token interceptor to http client

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
private Disposable disposable;

@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

//        if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
//
//            synchronized (chain) {
//
//
//                RefreshTokenApi refreshTokenApi = new RefreshTokenApi();
//                disposable = refreshTokenApi.call().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
//                        (tokenResponse, throwable) -> {
//
//                            PreferencesWrapperImpl.SINGLETON.putStringForKey(tokenResponse.getResponse().header(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN), Constants.PreferenceKey.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
//                            Log.e("throwable", throwable.getMessage());
//
//                        });
//
//
//                Request newRequest = request.newBuilder()
//                        .removeHeader(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN)
//                        .addHeader(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN, PreferencesWrapperImpl.SINGLETON.getStringForKey(Constants.PreferenceKey.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, null))
//                        .build();
//                response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
//            }
//        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

then i discovered that the request proceed many times so i thought that maybe my synchronized logic wrong and that is what caused request to occur multiple time so i commented the synchronized logic but actually the request still occur many times

and here is my logcat

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://134.209.26.2:88/api/common/version/check http/1.1
```

D/OkHttp:

```
 --> POST http://134.209.26.2:88/api/common/version/check http/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 35
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 35
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMzQuMjA5LjI2LjI6ODhcL2FwaVwvc3BcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg3NjQxMjY5LCJleHAiOjE1ODc2NzcyNjksIm5iZiI6MTU4NzY0MTI2OSwianRpIjoiZThXQUpIenVSamdGOGpORyIsInN1YiI6MTMsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEiLCJwaWQiOjUsInR5cGUiOjF9.sA3-Ga9YI-4AyDZV_KIuOukONu3Abblq6ge8JbaMgp8
    x-lang-code: en-us
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMzQuMjA5LjI2LjI6ODhcL2FwaVwvc3BcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg3NjQxMjY5LCJleHAiOjE1ODc2NzcyNjksIm5iZiI6MTU4NzY0MTI2OSwianRpIjoiZThXQUpIenVSamdGOGpORyIsInN1YiI6MTMsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEiLCJwaWQiOjUsInR5cGUiOjF9.sA3-Ga9YI-4AyDZV_KIuOukONu3Abblq6ge8JbaMgp8
D/OkHttp: x-user-type: 1
D/OkHttp: x-lang-code: en-us
    x-user-type: 1
D/OkHttp: {"user_platform":1,"version":"1.0"}
    --> END POST (35-byte body)
D/OkHttp: {"user_platform":1,"version":"1.0"}
    --> END POST (35-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://134.209.26.2:88/api/common/version/check (446ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 22:01:29 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://134.209.26.2:88/api/common/version/check (447ms)
D/OkHttp: Vary: Authorization
D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 22:01:29 GMT
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
D/OkHttp: Vary: Authorization
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 46
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 46
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: application/json
    {"data":{"status":1,"min":null,"latest":null}}
D/OkHttp: {"data":{"status":1,"min":null,"latest":null}}
    <-- END HTTP (46-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (46-byte body)
E/APP_UPDATES: onSuccess
```

i use logging interceptor to so as you see the first request of app which is app updates post many times

Comment: "but actually the code still occur many times" -- could you explain in greater detail what you mean and how you determined that this is happening?

Comment: oh, sorry i meant the request

Comment: How have you determined that "the request still occur many times"? If you remove the interceptor from your `OkHttpClient.Builder`, does the problem go away? Your interceptor does not do anything, so it should not be causing any problems.

Comment: actually i remove the interceptor, but from logcat i can still found request occur  many times, but when i debugging the call function and the response function happend only once so is it logging thing or what happen?

Comment: Did you somehow add the logging interceptor twice?

Comment: no i don't, i only added once

Comment: If you comment out the interceptor and run your app, do you still see the interception logs? If so, the perhaps something else is adding the same interceptor. Also, is this your server? If so, check the server logs to see if the server is getting one or two requests.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot i will check server side